# can we use Bluetooth dongle both on Host (xp) and Guest android OS at a time

Tags: android, windows, bluetooth, virtualbox

I wanted to implement communication between c# server and android application through bluetooth. I don't have real android device so I am using android emulator in Virtualbox.

1. I have activated bluetooth in android emulator but unable to share bluetooth between both xp and VM android. My pc does not have bluetooth internal hardware. I am using Bluetooth Dongle. How can I share same bluetooth device both on xp and VM android?
2. I wanted to establish communication between c# server running on host xp and VM android emulator by using same bluetooth dongle. is it possible to discover and connect android emulator from host xp using same bluetooth dongle?

Sorry If I ask anything silly or or my way of questioning is not right. I don;t have much knowledge about all this stuff.

Thanks everyone for help!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is not possible (I also wanted to do it but couldn't make it work).
What would be interesting, is if it's possible to connect 2 separate BT dongles to a single computer and get them to pair.

Comment: so, it means its not possible to do it on single dongle and even with 2 on same pc. :(

Comment: I don't have real device and desperately need it urgently. is there any way?

Comment: I haven't tried with 2 on one PC, I used a laptop with built in bluetooth. If you have 2 dongles give it a go and let us know.